# What's the error in my program?

Tags: c, logic

I had written this C program :

```
main()
{
int i,k;
char a[]="ilovefootbalonly\n";
printf("enter 1 or 2\n");
scanf("%d",&k);
switch(k)
{
    case'1':for(i=0;i<=16;i++)
    {
        i+=1;
        printf("%-16.*s\n",i,a);
    }
    break;
    case'2':for(i=16;i>=0;i--)
    {
        i+=1;
        printf("%*.*s\n",16,i,a);

    }
    break;
}
```

}

And I expected my output to be something like this after i enter 1 :

```
i

il

ilo

ilov

.

.

.

.

ilovefootbal
```

Even though my program is compiled error free but when I run it, after I enter `1` or `2`, it stops there, so where do I commit any mistake ?

Am a newbie to stack overflow and C, so I'll be grateful if you excuse any minor errors in posting such a question.

Comment: " case'1' "  you ae comparing a character constant against the input value read as an integer. 1 != '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case labels are incorrect. You mean 1 and 2, not `'1'` and `'2'`. The latter are *character* literals (which have numeric values of 49 and 50).

Also, due to a typo with "football", your string actually consists of 16 characters (plus a terminator). Either fix that, or run your loop to 15 rather than 16.

Another thing, is that your loop in case 2 will never terminate: the `i--` will cancel the `i += 1` in the loop body. In a similar vein, case 1 will run through the index with twice the intended frequency.

And do consider using `int main()` as the function prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The program stops because it reaches the end of program. Change "case '1':" to `case 1:` and `case '2':` to `case 2:`, then it should jump into case 1 or 2. Furthermore you are increasing i twice. First in `for(i=0;i<=16;i++){` and `i+=1;`. I not sure if this behaviour is correct ;-).

Comment: I incremented `i` because I thought since, I am allocating 16 places out of 20, so one extra should be there for `\0` at the end as it's a string.

Comment: well, did you implement the changes? So you coudl tell us whats your output. I guess it will skipp each 2. character.

Comment: Well the output is fine except the fact that it does not stop just at `ilovefootbal` but stops at `ilovefootbalonly`.....I think that could be corrected if I restrict `i<=12`

Comment: Plus one for spotting the twice increasing case.